# How can I install librados on mac osx?

Tags: macos, go, ceph

I want to develop a object storage appliaction using ceph. Official client library include java/c++/php/python but exclude golang. Our team use golang as primary develop language and mac osx as default develop environment.

[go-ceph](https://github.com/ceph/go-ceph) is a golang client for ceph, but it requires libredos, but I don't know how to install librados on maxos.

thanks you~

Comment: Documents about install librados posted [here](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/hammer/rados/api/librados-intro/)

Answer (score 2):

Find a simple APIs to access any Amazon S3 compatible object storage: [Minio Go Client SDK for Amazon S3 Compatible Cloud](https://github.com/minio/minio-go).

Do not need to install a client on osx.

thanks.